# using 2 google maps on 2 different pages, one is working but the second works only after a refresh apparently

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a site that is using google map api (src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...).

- One page has a map with location marker that user can click on it.
- When a user click on a map, he may choose to view the detail of that location.
- the detailed location includes two maps (a satellite view and a street view).

The problem is that when you land to the second page you only see google map frame but there is no map. In order to get a map I have to include an alert() function that will execute after the first load, then the map shows without problem.
I am a little new to google map api, I don't understand this behavior.
the code for the google maps are in a js file, the html file where the map is inserted is in another file (.php).
So the question is why do I have to reload or use the 'alert(yahoo)' below (that I have commented out) in order for the map to load.. Here is how the code looks like:

```
function initialize_single_location() {
 var currentdate = get_current_date();

$.getJSON(some code go here)
        .done(function (data) {
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              if(some codes go here)
                {

                    position_lat = data[i].lat;
                    position_long = data[i].long;
                    address=data[i].address;
                    city=data[i].city;
                    state=data[i].state;
                    zip=data[i].zip;
                    name=data[i].name; 
                   $('#myAddress').html('<strong>'+data[i].name +'</strong><br>' + data[i].address + '<br>' + data[i].city + ' ' + data[i].state + ' '
                    + data[i].zip + '<br>' +'Telephone: Not Provided' + '<br> Fax: Not Provided');
                   var direction = document.getElementById("directions");
                   direction.setAttribute("href", "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//"+address+"+"+city+"+"+state+"+"+zip+"");

                 } 

            }
        })
        .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            alert("Request Failed: " + err);
        });
          //alert('yahoo');
  var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(position_lat, position_long);

  var mapOptions = {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map-canvas2'), mapOptions);
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: fenway,
    pov: {
      heading: 34,
      pitch: 10
    }
  };

  var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'),panoramaOptions);
  map.setStreetView(panorama);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize_single_location);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem because of asynchronous nature of `$getJSON()` call. It returns immediately and initialization of map starts after that. Variable `fenway` is most probably undefined so map cannot be properly initialized. That is why `alert()` helps. While you close the alert window, variables from `$getJSON.done()` are set and everything works fine after that.

You have to move all that code for map initialization to `.done()` part of `$getJSON()` call or  make it a function and call it at the end of `.done()` part.

Comment: Anto Jurković, Thanks a lot! it worked like a charm; You added to my knowledge of $getJSON(), I had no idea of its asynchronous nature; yes moving the map initialization inside done resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your `addDomListener`, call a function that checks to see if the `map-canvas` is visible (for landing directly on this page/tab). If so, initialize the map. I also added a `document.ready` check that calls the visibility check function when switching from another page/tab:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    mapVisible();
});

function mapVisible() {
    if (!$("#googft-mapCanvas").is(":visible")) return;                      

    initialize_single_location();
}

//this will call it if you land directly on this page/tab
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', mapVisible);
```

We used this with jQuery tabs, and switching to a second tab doesn't reinitiate the `window load` event. This worked around that.